# Sums of powers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

Here's the problem:

> Show that $19^{19}$ is not the sum of a fourth power and a positive or negative cube.

I'm just not really sure how to start approaching this problem. Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: Hmm this looks exactly like a question I did before on an example sheet for year 1 mathematics at Cambridge. Here's a small hint: You want to find a prime $p$, such that not too many residues $\pmod{p}$ are fourth powers, and not all residues $\pmod{p}$ are cubes.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.